# websocket vs http vs spdy

Tags: http, websocket, spdy

I am quite new to web development. I have read about different approach to Web data exchange. For now I have discovered people have invented generally three protocols for web: *http*, *websocket* and *spdy*. And now I am stuck. If I had choice to implement my own application - which protocol to use? It is said *http* is very old and slow comparing to others. From the other side I can not find many examples with *websocket* or *spdy* in internet.

Comment: Different protocols have different strengths.  So, the answer for what to use really depends upon exactly what you're trying to do.  I don't think we can really help you much until you describe what you're actually trying to do with your "web data exchange".  Is this from browser to server, from server to browser, from app to server, from server to server?  And, how often is the data sent? How big is the data?  Do you need to "push" data from one end to the other or can one side just request data when it wants new data?

Comment: I am going to start project. What I want to create - modern up-to-technologies site. I want it to be fast. No big data is expected. I dont expect clients will need up-to-date statistics from the site.

Answer (score 2):

**All requests in a modern browser start out as HTTP/1.1**

HTTP/1.1 is the de facto standard of the modern web.  In order to achieve wide browser support, your application must support HTTP/1.1.

SPDY, HTTP/2, and WebSockets are protocols that most modern browsers support.  Requests to use these protocols start out as HTTP/1.1 requests, and are upgraded if both the browser and the server support the protocol.

Most of the time the actual implementation of these protocols is left to a Web Server, such as Apache or NGINX.  First, decide what language you want to write your application with.  Next, research how to configure your web server to be used with your language.

**HTTP/1.1, SPDY, and HTTP/2 are for Loading Resources**

When you visit a page in the browser, it is downloaded over HTTP.  Any scripts, stylesheets, images, etc. that the page references are also loaded over HTTP.

If you'd like to benefit from a faster protocol for loading pages, research how to enable HTTP/2 for your web server.  HTTP/2 is based on SPDY and is approved by a standards board.  It's supported in the latest versions of Apache and NGINX, but requires that the site be served over SSL/TLS.

**Web Sockets are Initiated by Scripts**

Once your application loads, a script on the page can initiate a Web Socket connection.  This connection is held open to perform real-time communication between the browser and the server for as long as the page is open.

You would typically only use web sockets in a Single Page Application (SPA).  If you are using a Javascript Framework for your frontend such as AngularJS or React, research how to implement Web Sockets through the framework.  You'll also need to configure a web socket handler on your server, and will likely need to configure a Web Socket proxy on your Web Server.